# Third party payment gateway or In App Purchase

Tags: ios, payment

I have an application where the user will have to buy licenses firstly to create other supporting users of this application. For example, a parent will buy 2 licenses to create a kid and his caretaker account so that they can use the application with respective credentials. This application has an Android version and web portal too. All the three platforms are synced I.e. all the users can log in on these platforms.

Earlier the purchase of licenses was done from a web portal. Now we have a requirement to make the mobile application purchase the licenses and integrate the payment gateway in it.

I want to use a third-party payment gateway so that the same user can access the services on the different platforms as well. If I will plan to integrate third-party payment gateway, is there any chance that Apple can reject my application.

Also is it mandatory to use the in-app purchase in this scenario or I can use the third-party payment gateway?

Comment: It's not mandatory to use Apple in-App payment. You can use any third party like Stripe, Paytm, MasterCard etc.

Comment: No In App Purchase is not mandatory. you can use any Payment Methods like Stripe , Paypal , Paytm , G-PAy/ApplePay etc.

Comment: Here is a simple idea, if the item/service is digital and going to be used inside the app then in-app purchase else you are free to use any third-party payment vendor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use in-app purchases for digital goods and other payments for physical goods.

---

More info:

> There are a couple different ways to integrate payments into your iOS
>   app: Apple Pay and In-App Purchases. It’s important to understand when
>   each option should be used.
>
> You can use Apple Pay to sell physical goods such as groceries,
>   clothing, and appliances. Also use Apple Pay for services such as club
>   memberships, hotel reservations, and tickets for events. These
>   transactions will be processed through Stripe and you’ll only need to
>   pay Stripe’s processing fee. You can read more about Apple Pay here.
>
> You are required to use Apple’s In-App Purchase API to sell virtual
>   goods such as premium content for your app, and subscriptions for
>   digital content. Specifically, Apple’s developer terms require that
>   the In-App Purchase API must be used for digital “content,
>   functionality, or services” such as premium features or credits. If
>   you use the In-App Purchase API, the transactions will be processed by
>   Apple, which will charge a fee of 30% of the total transaction.

---

Docs: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios#using-stripe-and-apple-pay-vs-in-app-purchases